# Python eve validation with value from another property

Tags: eve

I have a schema with some fields and my custom validation for a given field requires that I know the value of another field in order to make a decision whether that field is valid or not. Think of accessing the `cleaned_data` in Django.

Here's a simple scenario where I need the value of `end_date` to validate a `start_date`:

```
class MyValidator( Validator ):

    def _validate_start_date( self, is_start_date, field, value ):
        ...get the value from end_date and make sure end_date is bigger than start_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `self.document` to retrieve other fields values. Pseudo code would be something like this:

```
class MyValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_start_date(self, is_start_date, field, value):
        end_date = self.document.get('end_date')
        return end_date is not None and value < end_date
```